# Programatically execute a SPAN's Class from DOM Element?

Tags: html, .net, dhtml

This is a .NET program, and I am accessing the `HTMLElements` individually.  There are pieces of markup that have a "More..." / "Less..." in a SPAN tag, that when Clicked will show more/less of the preceding content,

A code snippet:

```html
<dd>
Product Manager, Business Analysis & Web Design Manager, Global Portals at Dun & Bradstreet
<span class="toggle-show-more"> less...</span>
</dd>
```

The "less.." is click-able, which then invokes something to display less text.  I would like to do the same from an HtmlElement programatically.

And, some Command window output from Visual Studio:

OuterHtml: "

```html
<DD collapsed="False">Product Manager, Business Analysis &amp; Web Design Manager, Global Portals at Dun &amp; Bradstreet "
OuterText: "Product Manager, Business Analysis & Web Design Manager, Global Portals at Dun & Bradstreet "
```

I have tried: `elem.RaiseEvent("onlick")` and toggling the "collapsed" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an onclick to the span that disappears the dd? Something like:

```
onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'"
```